# Orthogonal complement of $\mathrm{im}\ T$ for a $G$-invariant transformation $T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, proof-explanation

I am having trouble determining the orthogonal complement of the image of a transformation $T$. I need to show that $(\mathrm{im}\ T)^{\perp}$ is a $G$-invariant subspace.

I have a $G$-invariant transformation $T:V\rightarrow W$, where $V$ and $W$ are representations of $G$, and $\dim V = 12$ and $\dim W = 20$. I also know that $\dim \ker T=1$ and $\ker T = \left\{k\begin{bmatrix} 1 & ... & 1 \end{bmatrix}^{T}\ \ |\ \ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & ... & 1 \end{bmatrix}^{T}\in V\right\}$.

By the dimension formulas, we know that $$\dim \ker T + \dim \mathrm{im}\ T = \dim V = 12$$
Thus, $\dim \mathrm{im}\ T = 11$.

Similarly, since $(\mathrm{im}\ T)^{\perp} \oplus \mathrm{im}\ T = W $, then
$$\dim (\mathrm{im}\ T)^{\perp}  + \dim \mathrm{im}\ T = \dim W = 20$$
Thus, $\dim (\mathrm{im}\ T)^{\perp} = 9$

And since $(\ker T)^{\perp} \oplus \ker T = V $, then
$$\dim (\ker T)^{\perp}  + \dim \ker T = \dim V = 12$$
Thus, $\dim (\ker T)^{\perp} = 11$.

At this point, I don't know if any of this will be helpful.

I also know that $$(\mathrm{im}\ T)^{\perp} = \ker T^T$$ and that $$\mathrm{im}\ T \cong V/\ker T$$

So I tried to determine the vectors orthogonal to the cosets of $\ker T$ in $V$, but this also seems too complicated considering what is given...

Any suggestions for determining the orthogonal complement of the image of $T$ explicitly?

**Edit:** If $T:V\rightarrow W$ is $G$-invariant, would that imply that $T^{T}:W\rightarrow V$ is also $G$-invariant? If this is true, then I think that I know how I would show that $\mathrm{im}\ T$ is $G$-invariant.